# Can I use keycloak as an Idp for kibana installed using the ElasticSearch Operator in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch, keycloak

I have setup a kubernetes cluster in a private network and I'm using a gateway machine for accessing the cluster. In the kubernetes cluster I have installed the elasticsearch operator and through that I have created an elastic cluster and a kibana instance. In the gateway machine a nginx reverse proxy is providing access to both kibana and elastic.

The official documentation in the elastic site (and also a ton of tutorials I found online) describe how to use keycloak to provide SSO with kibana but the catch is that they are using the xpack.security extension of elasticsearch, whose configuration is not available to clusters created using the operator (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-reserved-settings.html). Moreover, the instructions require to enable ssl between the elastic nodes, something that has not been necessary so far, since my cluster is completely private and thus secure and ssl is configured in the gateway reverse proxy.

So, my question is if there is a way to integrate kibana and elastic (installed using the elastic operator in kubernates) with keycloak, preferably without having to enable ssl in the cluster.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Keycloak as an IdP for Kibana installed using the ElasticSearch Operator in Kubernetes. However, you will need to configure Kibana to use Keycloak as the authentication provider using SAML or OpenID Connect protocols. This can be done without enabling SSL in the cluster, but you may need to make some adjustments to your NGINX reverse proxy configuration to ensure secure communication between Kibana and Keycloak.